# REGEX replace line for forum threads

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace text from an outdated mod on a forum.  The old code looked like this

```
[ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYJ20INbM7Q"]YouTube - &#x202a;Bill O'Reilly Interviews Rapper Lupe Fiasco - 06/20/11&#x202c;&rlm;[/ame]
```

I want the new code to look like this:

```
[video=youtube;wYJ20INbM7Q]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYJ20INbM7Q[/video]YouTube - Bill O'Reilly Interviews Rapper Lupe Fiasco - 06/20/11[/video]
```

I used:

```
$text = preg_replace('[ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="([a-z0-9]+)\"],
([video=youtube;$2]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$2[/video])', $text);
```

Error: Warning: Wrong parameter count for `preg_replace()`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Currently, your desired output has the form: `[video]...[/video]...[/video]`. This seems erroneous to me (i.e. only 1 open tag with 2 close tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, your code won't do what you want it to. Use these instead.

```
$regEx = '#\[ame\=".*?\=([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)"]#';
$replacement = "([video=youtube;$1]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1[/video])";
$text = preg_replace($regEx, $replacement, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I needed.  Weird after I changed the lines it did not do anything to the test forum thread.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept an answer. It helps your reputation and the respondant's

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes before and after the first comma in your parameter list

```
$text = preg_replace('|\[ame="http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+)"\]|i', '[video=youtube;$1]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1[/video]', $text);
```

Also, your regex has a number of syntax errors:

1. You need to identify the start and end of your pattern (I used `|` above)
2. You need to escape your square brackets
3. You don't need to escape your quote, and you have an extra quote after v=
4. You need an `i` modifier to make your match case-insensitive

Comment: Also, he needs to escape `=` and `.`